# Rails renders wrong URL with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not really sure what going on here. After nesting the resources like this

```
resources :users do
    resources :bookmarks
end
```

I expected the url should be `/users/[user-id]/bookmarks/[bookmark-id]/edit`, but rails renders a reverse path `/users/[bookmark-id]/bookmarks/[user-id]/edit`

This is the view

```
<%= link_to 'edit', edit_user_bookmark_path(@bookmark) %>
```

Any idea how to fix it ? Thanks

Comment: can you show result of `rake routes`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you expect is [the rule](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Replace with:

```
<%= link_to 'edit', edit_user_bookmark_path(current_user, @bookmark) %>
```